# Browserify private global variable

Tags: javascript, browserify

How can I create a private custom global variable with `browserify`?
For example, a variable wich is accessible from all the browserify files (`require()`) but not outside the `browserify` block, `console` or others scripts cannot access to it.
I've tried global, but It's accessible from window / console.

EDIT: no answers? I really needs that to prevent self XSS (for eg, malicious scripts to stole user data or to send bad packets to delete his rooms ect...)

**Example code:**

Main.js

```
mycustomglobal.test  = require('blabla');
mycustomglobal.test2 = require('blablablabla');

var users = require('./users.js');
```

Users.js file:

```
console.log(mycustomglobal);
// we need to be able to get test and test2
```

Console / or other script

```
console.log(mycustomglobal)
// we need to get undefined
```

Comment: I don't think you can. Probably the closest you can get is to define a module with a private variable with an API to access that variable from the other JS - but that API also leaves it open to inspection with the console. What do you intend to keep in this variable?

Comment: I intend to keep my game different objects, for example one for the UI, one for the canvas, another for sounds ect... 
To make data more harder to be edited or got with the console, I want to do that

Comment: This might help you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-global-shim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this would suit your needs. You need to create a module, which I prefer to name `private_globals.js`:

```
var globals={};
module.exports=globals;
```

In your other files, you can use this module's exported object.

```
var globals=require("./private_globals")
console.log(globals.privateVar1);
globals.privateVar2=10;
```

I can think of no other way, unless you mess with source of browserify.

Comment: globals.privateVar2 is accessible (get and set) to everything (unless I'm missing something?)

Comment: It should be only accessible after getting the globals object with require. If require is not exposed, you cannot get the globals object. I am not sure if this will work between bundles though.

Comment: But the only way for require not to be exposed is for it to be encapsulated. Otherwise, if OP wanted to use the globals, they would no longer be private.

Comment: require is not a global function. It is only defined in the module. See [How Browserify Works](http://benclinkinbeard.com/posts/how-browserify-works/)

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks for that link, I did not realise it would be wrapped in an IIFE. I apologise for my ignorance :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve (maybe post some more code), but I assume you want to do something without exposing globals? Can you use a immediately-invoked function? As long as all your code is inside the function, everything will be protected but nothing will functionally change:

```
(function() {
    var module = require('your_module'),
        connection = new WebSocket('server.php'),
        data = [{score: 12, name: 'test'}, {score: 40, name: 'user1'}];
    // ... Your other code
})();
```

If you have many scripts, you might have to wrap those in functions and then call them from your main script with the IIF, passing any arguments so that they don't leak:

js_file_1.js:

```
(function() {
    var private_non_global = 1234;
    // Do some stuff...
    script2(private_non_global); // Go to next script...
})();
```

js_file_2.js:

```
function script2(private_non_global_from_script1) {
    private_non_global_from_script1 === 1234;
    // Do more stuff, etc.
}
```

If you can change things server-side you could wrap all your code inside one huge IIF. You can't have any globals that are only accessible to your code, as anyone could open the console to access any global variable. The only way to protect variables is to encapsulate all your code.

Comment: That's not exactly what I want. I don't want to pass the variable to the other script with a function, but I want to make something like the global variable, but stays private

Comment: That's an oxymoron, you just can't have that (at least not in JavaScript). If you don't want to "expose" global variables, you have to use scoping.

Comment: Think of it like this: global variables give the same rights to everyone. Upside: Your variable is accessible to all your scripts and scopes. Downside: It's also accessible to anything else, e.g. unknown code, the console, browser extensions, other libraries, etc.

Comment: so, is it impossible to declare a custom "global" variable wich is only inside browserify block?

Comment: Maybe add some example code for context, and give exact examples of what you want to happen and don't. Then we could maybe help you find a better solution, because globals is probably not what you want.